# Android TabHost Fragment Switch

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using TabHost and I have a problem. What I want is first tab should be a FragmentActivity and it can switch to another Fragments. This [application](https://github.com/snowpong/stacksintabs) helps me but I have also questions. In this example, you can go to infinite another Fragments but it's happening by the help of launchNewFragment method and this method is called from xml. But I need to call this method programmatically because when button is clicked, I also want to move some values (such as selected values in dialog) to another Fragment. Or is there another way to solve this problem? I'm waiting your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Action Bar with Tabs instead of TabHost. You can get information about how to use it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

No matter on the chosen solution, replacing the displayed fragment in an activity is done like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new MyFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

You just have to add this to the button listener and replace MyFragment with your fragment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I changed my question a little. Could you please help me again?